# Ionic: livereload not working after including custom webpack.config.js

Tags: ionic-framework, webpack, ionic2

After I finished updating typescript file, app-script does proceed a build process, but the result remains the same. *Every time I make changes, restarting a server is a very annoying job to do*.

For example,
when I changed a single line of code from `console.log('ABC')` to `console.log('DEF')`, console prints out `ABC` again.

> I have reproduced a sample Ionic 3 project to test `livereload` without using a custom web pack config file, and everything went great.

It seems like I missed out something in my custom config file. What am I doing wrong here?

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpackDefault = require('@ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');

const customConfig = {
  dev: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@myproject-app': path.resolve('src/app'),
        '@myproject-environments': path.resolve('src/environments'),
        '@myproject-pages': path.resolve('src/pages'),
      }
    }
  },
  prod: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@myproject-app': path.resolve('src/app'),
        '@myproject-environments': path.resolve('src/environments'),
        '@myproject-pages': path.resolve('src/pages'),
      }
    }
  }
};

module.exports = webpackMerge(webpackDefault, customConfig);
```

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.7
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 browser ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2
Node       : v8.9.0
npm        : 5.5.1
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

Comment: I am having the same exact issue :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I solved my problem was following the steps from [gshigeto/ionic-environment-variables](https://github.com/gshigeto/ionic-environment-variables). I don't have to duplicate the original configuration. I hope this answer helps others.

```
const chalk = require("chalk");
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const useDefaultConfig = require('@ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config.js');

let env = process.env.IONIC_ENV;

useDefaultConfig.prod.resolve.alias = {
  "@projectname-app": path.resolve('src/app'),
  "@projectname-components": path.resolve('src/components'),
  "@projectname-core": path.resolve('src/core'),
  "@projectname-env": path.resolve(environmentPath('prod')),
  "@projectname-pages": path.resolve('src/pages'),
};

useDefaultConfig.dev.resolve.alias = {
  "@projectname-app": path.resolve('src/app'),
  "@projectname-components": path.resolve('src/components'),
  "@projectname-core": path.resolve('src/core'),
  "@projectname-env": path.resolve(environmentPath('dev')),
  "@projectname-pages": path.resolve('src/pages'),
};

if (env !== 'prod' && env !== 'dev') {
  // Default to dev config
  useDefaultConfig[env] = useDefaultConfig.dev;
  useDefaultConfig[env].resolve.alias = {
    "@projectname-env": path.resolve(environmentPath(env))
  };
}

function environmentPath(env) {
  var filePath = './src/environments/environment' + (env === 'prod' ? '' : '.' + env) + '.ts';
  if (!fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
    console.log(chalk.red('\n' + filePath + ' does not exist!'));
  } else {
    return filePath;
  }
}

module.exports = function () {
  return useDefaultConfig;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue as you, with the same exact implementation.  I was able to fix this by simply copying the original ionic webpack config and pasting it into my custom webpack config file.  Obviously not as clean as the webpack-merge solution but it works.

Comment: I've just posted an answer. It fixed all my issues.